# USB power doe Arduino

Tags: usb, power-supply, arduino

How good is the power regulation on a RPi 2 ?

I have a small robot controlled by an RPi2 and some Arduinos, and have two choices to power it (the Pi, that is). I can make a dedicated 5V regulated rail with a small 3A DC-DC converter, or I can feed the 7.4V from the batteries to the Pi. The batteries will have servos (via another regulator) running off them, possible not a real clean source, but maybe OK with the other 5V regulator for the servos there.

My other question is power related too. How can I stop the Pi from giving the Arduino power over USB? It really only needs to be a data connection and I'd rather supply the Arduinos off my own 5V rail than tax the Pi's USB.

Sorry about the two questions / post, they seem related.

Comment: If you feed the 7.4V from the battery to the Pi the question becomes moot, as you no longer have a working Pi.

Comment: Ah, very sorry. I had thought the Pi had a regulator and provision for battery power, my mistake.

Comment: I use a UBEC in your situation.  They will produce 5V suitable for the Pi and your servos.